Application Error on Azure Web Service after deploying Node.js API using Azure DevOps
I am new to Azure and currently trying to deploy a Node.js API using Azure DevOps pipelines to Azure Web Services. The deployment process seems to complete without errors, but when I visit the URL provided by Azure for my API, I encounter the following error:

:( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the

Here is my azure-pipelines.yml file for reference:
trigger:
- main

variables:
  webAppName: 'api'
  environmentName: 'api'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '20.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: api'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|20.x'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'node dist/src/services/server.js'

Could anyone please help me identify what might be going wrong or what steps I could take to diagnose and resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am quite new to Azure.
Here is my JSON file:
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/src/services/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "migrate": "node-pg-migrate",
    "migrate-up": "DATABASE_URL=$(azureSubscription) npm run migrate up"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.24",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "node-pg-migrate": "^6.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}



if you go into the pipeline run and download the artifact, does it contain the expected build output?

Hi there, have you tried to build and deploy your NodeJS app locally without using pipeline? Could the issue still be reproduced, or it only occurred after build and deployment via pipeline? It would be helpful to isolate the cause of the issue.

@DerekGusoff Yes the build folder contains everything and I also run the build folder locally it worked fine.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT It runs fine locally I aslo downloaded the zip folder of the artifact and it worked perfectly fine on my machine

Hi BugHunter, Thanks for the feedback, but I mean if you could build your app and deploy it to Azure App Service from local machine without using pipeline, so as to check if it could be running.

Similar to the pipeline automation workflow, you may test to use this command az webapp deploy --resource-group rg-appservice --name MyNodeJSApp --src-path artifact.zip to deploy artifact file to Azure App Service via local Azure CLI or CloudShell.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Thank you for your suggestion. I've successfully built the app locally and manually deployed it to Azure App Service using the Azure VSCode extension. However, it's worth noting that the deployment through the pipeline did not work as expected, so there seems to be an issue with the pipeline configuration that needs to be addressed.

Thanks for the update. Would please check the answer below to configure the startup command for your NodeJS web app with npm run start? You can also set the command via pipeline during deployment as suggested by SiddheshDesai.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT You are welcome and I tried that command yesterday but it didnt work.

Try using the another startup command with npm run start to start your nodejs express api like below:-
My Azure devops yaml pipeline code:-
trigger:
- master

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: '7b855bca-812f-408b-bf9c-b66901432ec1'

  
  webAppName: 'siliconwebapp43'

 
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapp43'

 
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: siliconwebapp43'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'

Output:-




Thanks, I tried this command and it didnt help

Okay, This is my package.json - {
"name": "myexpressapp",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www"
},
"dependencies": {
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"ejs": "~2.6.1",
"express": "~4.16.1",
"http-errors": "~1.6.3",
"morgan": "~1.9.1"
}
} which have worked for me

Can you try my yaml pipeline code for deployment and check?

Have you hardcoded the $(azureSubscription) from "migrate-up": "DATABASE_URL=$(azureSubscription) npm run migrate up" in your json file? Please check in your pipeline build artifact zip file if all the file contents are correct and then check the Advanced tools of your web app to see if the same artifacts with expected contents were extracted in to /home/site/wwwroot/.

@BugHunter, in addition, you can also check and share your app running logs in the Stream logs tab of the Advanced tools site.
